# Registering users

Tags: registration, livechat

I am working on a chat app project like [intercom](http://intercom.com) and i have a problem with registering users or rather another website's visitors. They don't want visitors to register but when you have a chat they store it and remember it later. So i want to know which way should i turn to? Registering users based on their IP address or store a cookie in visitor's browser or any other way that i might not be familiar with?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Store it in user localstorage, store an object with all the informations you need and also the last chat history.

Localstorage is limited but for this kind of service you can store just one at time, when new chat happen override the object stored.

Well, my first view point about the problem you have to solve bring me to this solution.

Comment: thanks for answering me. i thought about it but it seems they don't store anything like it!

Comment: I see,  go with IP, because now the user can deny the website to store a cookie. But you will have a problem with IP as we can have a network with multiple users and one IP reaching your end.

Comment: well, possible go with Cookie and let user know if he don't accept store a cookie he will have no history?

Comment: Well i did a little bit of research in their app they do store a cookie but i'd like to do a combination of ip, cookie and localstorage.